# Htaccess search redirect with query parameters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've run into a problem with the way that search on my site is working, and I couldn't find a great example of this issue on here.  When a user submits an empty search the search doesn't function correctly.  However, if I put a plus sign in the search parameter search works fine; even when the search is empty.  I was thinking that I could use htaccess to fix this issue.  Here's what I've got so far:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=$
RewriteRule ^ /?s=+ [L,R=301]
```

This works fine if the url is like:

> http://mysite.com/?s=

However, my search queries more often look like:

> http://mysite.com/?s=&zipcode=XXXXX&submit=Submit

Where XXXXX is a zip code.  Is there a way to allow this redirect to fire, even if there are additional parameters behind the ?s= parameter while still preserving the additional parameters (for example, I wouldn't want to lose the zipcode parameter on redirect)?

Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=($|&.*$)
RewriteRule ^ /?s=+%1 [L,R=301]
```

The expression `($|&.*$)` creates a grouping that is either the end of the query string, or a `&` followed by whatever. This grouping is backreferenced using the `%1` in the rule.